# Check for space in string

Tags: php, string

Am working on a registration page for my site, and I want to format the username field to prevent users from submit username with space in between.
For example if a user submits a username like "space man", i want to change it to "space_man".
Am working with php, how do i go about it.

Comment: to change is not a good idea as they'll be unable to login trying "space man"

Comment: But am going to using the username in urls and spaces in url always throw errors

Comment: there is no problem with space in URL, if you know how to deal with them. Anyway, you have been asking how to "check" for a space, and it was right intention. To warn a user of illegal character is way better than silent replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm one of the best ways to do this is to validate at both places - client and server .

At the client, you must validate using javascript.

```
obj.value.replace(" ", "_");
alert("Invalid username. Changing space to underscore.");
```

Do the same thing on the server side too in php.

```
strstr($_POST['username'],' ','_');
```

If "space" is the only thing that matters to you, then this can be done. Else you ll have to write all the rules.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace(' ','_',$input);`

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple string replacement:

```
$username = str_replace(" ", "_", $username);
```

Answer (score 0):

I certainly appreciate [**strtr**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
strtr($_GET['username'],' ','_');
```

It's pretty powerful, too

```
strtr($_GET['username'],array(' '=>'_',"\t"=>'_'));
```

**str_replace**, obviously, works too.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace(' ', '_', $txtUserName);
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at http://www.php.net/str_replace - I'm sure you'll figure it out from there. Of course, there are many more things you'll want to validate against, so it's better to do white-list filtering (say what you allow, instead of what you don't allow), something like this regex:

```
if (! preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{3,32}$/', $_POST['username'])) {
    die('Invalid username'); // of course, dying is not good either, just for the example
}
```

Comment: Can any of the guys who downvoted give a reason? I'd really like to learn what's the problem with my answer.